# Sorting a String Column which has Decimal using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

ello,
   I have String Column which as decimal values in it example:
1.11 Env Doc - Class I
1.12 Env Doc - Class II
1.13 Env Doc - Class III
1.22 Geometric Layouts-Level 2
1.51 Public Involve - Level 1
10.1 Photogrammetric Mapping
10.21 Aerial Photography

i need to return this as 1.11...,1.12....,2.11...,2.12....etc
right now i am only using orderby clause on this column, Can you please help me here

```
var progTypes = (from mnuit in entities.MENU_ITEM
                                     join mnu in entities.MENU on mnuit.MENU_ID equals mnu.MENU_ID
                                     join prog in entities.PROG on mnuit.MENU_ITEM_ID equals prog.PROG_TYP_ID
                                     where (mnuit.MENU_ITEM_CD == programmodel.selectedProgram && mnu.MENU_NM == "PROG_TYP_ID" && prog.PROG_ACTV_FLG == programmodel.selectedProgStatus)
                                     select new ProgramModel.lstProgTypes
                                     {
                                         PROG_ID = prog.PROG_ID,
                                         PROG_NBR = prog.PROG_NBR,
                                         PROG_NM =  prog.PROG_NM,
                                         PROG_MAX_AMT = prog.PROG_MAX_AMT,
                                         PROG_START_DT = prog.PROG_START_DT,
                                         PROG_END_DT = prog.PROG_END_DT
                                     }).OrderBy(m=>m.PROG_NM).ToList();                                              
                    progModel.mProgTypes = progTypes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not fast, but you can try

```
.OrderBy(m=> Decimal.Parse(m.PROG_NM))
```

If you have large amount of data, you need to have a column with type of decimal and with index created on this column.

Comment: i tried using this but i get this error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: `Decimal.Parse(m.PROG_NM)` is not an SQL statement (LINQ to Entities requires that the the query can be converted to a SQL query) . Try calling `.ToList()` first, then the `.OrderBy()`

Comment: i used .ToList().OrderBy(m => m.PROG_NM); this did not work, is their their any other way i can achieve it